# Rails 3 , Jquery.load with no layout

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

My Ajax call is almost working, but i can't figure why my layout is still rendered?  here is the context:

I have a contact page on my site that use the linkedIn API.  I want to load the LinkedIn info from an ajax call when my page is loaded.  This work fine.

But the result of my .load() is rendered with the layout of my site.  I only want to render the html in my ajax_contact.html.erb..

contact.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $(".info_perso").load( '/contact/ajax_contact', {name:"benoit"}, function(data){  $(".info_perso").html( data );})

 });
```

ajax_contact.html.erb:

```
<%if !@profile.nil?%>

                <%=image_tag(@profile.picture_url)%><br />
                <%=@profile.first_name %> <%=@profile.last_name %><br>
                <%=@profile.headline%><br> 
                <%=@profile.industry%><br> <br />
                <%=@profile.summary%><br> 


                <label class="linkedin_title">Education</label><br>
                <% @profile.educations.all.each {|edu| %>

                    Degre : <%=edu.degree%><br>         
                    Années : <%=edu.start_date.year%> - <%=edu.end_date.year%><br>                      
                    Concentration : <%=edu.field_of_study%><br>         
                    Universite : <%=edu.school_name%><br>           
                <%}%>
                <label class="linkedin_title">Experience</label><br>
                <% @profile.positions.all.each {|pos| %>
                    <label class="linkedin_subtitle"> Company:</label> <%=pos.company.name%><br><br>                            
                    <label class="linkedin_subtitle">Titre :</label> <%=pos.title%><br>         
                    <label class="linkedin_subtitle">Années :</label> <%=pos.start_date.month%>/<%=pos.start_date.year%> - <%=  pos.end_date? ? pos.end_date.month.to_s + "/" + pos.end_date.year.to_s : "now"%><br>                        
                    <label class="linkedin_subtitle">Description :</label> <%=pos.summary%><br/><br/>           
                <%}%>

            <%else%>
                <%=link_to "Activer linkedIn", :controller=>"linkedinAuth", :action=>"benoit", :name=>"benoit", :callback=>"/linkedinauth/callbackbenoit"%>
            <%end%>
```

contact_controller.rb:

```
  def ajax_contact
name = params[:name]
linkedinInfo = LinkedinApiInfo.find(1)
linkedinCred = LinkedinCredential.find_by_name(name)
if !linkedinCred.nil?
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new(linkedinInfo.apiKey, linkedinInfo.secretKey)
  client.authorize_from_access(linkedinCred.acctoken, linkedinCred.accsecret)
  # Pick some fields
  fields = ['first-name', 'last-name', 'headline', 'industry', 'num-connections','educations', 'num-recommenders','recommendations-received', 'summary', 'positions','picture-url']

  @profile = client.profile :fields => fields
  @profile.recommendations_received.all.each {|rec| puts rec.recommendation_text}


  puts @profile

end
 rescue SocketError
  puts "Unable to connect"

  render "ajax_content", :content_type=>"text/html", :layout=>false

   end
```

Even with the :layout=>false, my layout is still showned!!!  anyone can see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

render 'ajax_contact', :layout=>false

to your action, at the end, also partial views name should start with _, so your view should be named '_ajax_contact'

Comment: rename your view to '_ajax_contact' then, so rails knows it's a partial view

Comment: did you change your render method also? you only have to change the name of the file.

Comment: Actually, i tried everything.  _ajax_contact.html.erb with render 'ajax_contact', :layout=>false.  then render '_ajax_context', :layout=>false.  then render :partial=>'ajax_context', :layout=>false...  I dont get it... worst thing, is i already did this with another project and all i had to to was to put render :layout=>false in my controller!!

Comment: omg... always a stupid mistake lol..  my render :layout=>false was at the end of the method... after my rescue SocketError....  so it was never called!  should have debug that before thanks for your time.  I will accept your response as a thanks ;-)